# Storing image to internal storage

Tags: android, storage, internal

I want to store my images to internal storage, I searched google and stackoverflow but couldn't get it done, Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ss);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
   // Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    //Firebase ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)
    {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

        // Find the SD Card path
        File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        // Create a new folder in SD Card
        File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                + "/Save Image Tutorial/");
        dir.mkdirs();

        // Create a name for the saved image
        File file = new File(dir, "myimage.png");

        // Show a toast message on successful save
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved to SD Card",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {

            output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

       // drawView.load_pic(picturePath);
    }
}
```

I want to get an image from the gallery and store it to internal storage but in this code, it is only saving the name of the file in the directory. If someone could help me to solve this.

Comment: Try to avoid all caps in sentences. You can check [ask] if you need more informations on how to ask.

Comment: Universal image loader library has the option to cache images in memory as well as in disk. Please check that

Answer (score 0):

you are writing Image file on external storage

```
File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

so check that you have mention proper permission in android manifest to write data on SD card

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and also get the bitmap from selected path

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
```

instead of

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE is request code not resource id of selected image

Comment: how to get the image from user  from gallery and store it in internal storage,how will this code get image from user?

Comment: yeah I hv done it,my problem is how to get image from user and store it in internal storage,for example I use this code to get image from user Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE); And how to store that image to internal storage

Comment: use BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath); to get bitmap of selected image, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE is not resource id of image that you selected it's request code

Answer (score 0):

You could use FileOutputStream to store your bitmap. After getting the bitmap from gallery, `FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream("fileName"); //Enter the desired filename
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }`

Comment: If my answer helped, kindly up-vote and mark my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**OnChoose Code**

```
        chooseimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){

                boolean result= Utility.checkPermission(getActivity());

                if(result) {
                    galleryIntent();
                }

            }

            else {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                // Start new activity with the LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS to handle back the results when image is picked from the Image Gallery.
                startActivityForResult(i,LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS); //LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS
            }




        }
    });
```

---

**Also Runtime permission added and Set image on your desired location**

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS) {
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);

            }
        }
    }
    else {



                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && isMediaDocument(data.getData())) {

                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(selectedImage);

                    // Split at colon, use second item in the array
                    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

                    String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    // where id is equal to
                    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

                    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().
                            query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                    column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

                    String filePath = "";

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        //filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        mPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    }


                    cursor.close();

                }
                else {
                    if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                        // Let's read picked image data - its URI
                        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
                        // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
                        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        mPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
                        //edAttach.setText(mPath.toString()); path set anywhere
                        cursor.close();
                    }

                }
    }
}




private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
ivprofile.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && isMediaDocument(data.getData())) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(selectedImage);

        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

        String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().
                query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

        String filePath = "";

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            mPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            //edAttach.setText(mPath); path set anywhere


        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    else {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        mPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex).toString();
        System.out.println("picturePath" + mPath);
        if (!mPath.equalsIgnoreCase(null)) {
            edAttach.setText(mPath);
        }
        cursor.close();


    }


    // Your Image Copy on Your desired location

  if(!mPath.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            // Create a new folder in SD Card
            File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/"+"Save Image Tutorial"+"/");
            dir.mkdirs();

            // Create a name for the saved image
            File file = new File(dir, "myImage.png");

            // Show a toast message on successful save


            try {

                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
                output.flush();
                output.close();


                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Saved to SD Card",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


}

public boolean hasPermissionInManifest(Context context, String permissionName) {
    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    try {
        final PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        final String[] declaredPermisisons = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
        if (declaredPermisisons != null && declaredPermisisons.length > 0) {
            for (String p : declaredPermisisons) {
                if (p.equals(permissionName)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    }
    return false;
}


 public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri)
{
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private void galleryIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                galleryIntent();

            } else {
                //code for deny
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**Or Permission In your mainfiest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Utility.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

public class Utility {
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context)
    {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(currentAPIVersion>= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```